# Get actual Model class in polymorphic method

Tags: django

I have a code like this with django-polymorphic. `A` base model is used as a foreign key in a `through=` model.

```
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('A')
        verbose_name_plural = _('As')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (
            unicode(self.name), self.__class__._meta.verbose_name)

    name = models.TextField()

class B(A):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('B')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Bs')


class C(A):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('C')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Cs')
```

But, in `QuerySet`s of `A`, `self.__class__` is always `A`, even with subclasses.

How to access the subclass in inherited methods like this?

Answer (score 0):

When set up correctly according to the documentation (http://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html#example), it works well on Admin. I have not tested in other views.